# carbon now. Disregard second param.

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to get all reminders for the current time, based on only the hour and minute parameters. How do i go about this?

```
reminders = Reminders::whereDate('scheduled_at', Carbon::now())
                              ->where('is_delivered', false)
                              ->get();
```

Comment: You can get it using `Carbon::now()->format('H:i')`. Please refer this link: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$reminders = Reminders::whereTime('scheduled_at', Carbon::now()->format('H:i'))
                          ->where('is_delivered', false)
                          ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`$reminders = Reminders::where('scheduled_at', Carbon::now())->where('is_delivered', false)->get();`